# PHP "хлебные крошки"

Tags: php, html

Здравствуйте! Необходимо сделать навигацию(хлебные крошки):[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом `Домой` является родителем для `Библиотека`, а `Библиотека` является родителем для `Данные`. Для это в бд в таблице была создана ячейка `parent_id` Вся информация хранится в базе и подгружается только на одну страницу. Как это можно реализовать? Как понять что сейчас нужны вывести `Данные`, а не `Библиотека`? Помогите кто чем может) P.S. Страницы (`Библиотека`, `Данные`, ...) формируются динамически

Comment: рекурсивный запрос от текущей страницы до родительского путем пока `parent_id` не равно `null`. Если `parent_id` существует, то в массив добавляем название страницы

Answer (score 2):

```
//Определяем переменную parent_id
$parent_id = isset($_GET['parent_id']) ? $_GET['parent_id'] : null;

function breadcrumb($cat, $id){
//Проверяем что ID это число
if(!intval($id)) return false;

//Создаем пустой массив
$brc = array();

//Перебираем полученый массив с меню
for($i = 0; $i < count($cat); $i++){
    //Проверяем что мы не нашли родителя и не массив пуст
    if($id != 0 and !empty($cat[$id])){
        //Ищем родителя
        $brc[$cat[$id]['id']] = $cat[$id]['title'];
        $id = $cat[$id]['parent'];
    }
    //Останавливаем цикл
    else break;
}
//Возвращаем перевернутый массив с сохранением ключей
return array_reverse($brc, true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Для это в бд в таблице была создана ячейка parent_id

Этого мало. Такая организация данных позволяет выбрать всех предков текущего раздела (что и нужно для "хлебных крошек") только рекурсивными обращениями к базе. Возможно, это можно обойти процедурой.

Существует четыре популярных метода хранения деревьев, чтобы различные их фрагменты можно было выбирать без рекурсии:

1. Adjacency List («список смежности»)
2. Materialized Path («материализованный путь»)
3. Nested Sets («вложенные множества»)
4. Closure Table («таблица связей»)

Информация отсюда: https://habrahabr.ru/post/193166/

Сам я пользуюсь обычно "Materialized Path" в упакованном виде (`path CHAR(248)`). Это автоматом вводит дополнительное (в другом месте архитектуры) ограничение на глубину дерева. Это самый простой "дубовый" (понятный) способ, и пофиг на лишние данные. Да и "Closure Table" это в принципе что-то подобное, только распакованное в отдельную реляцию, поэтому, он мне тоже нравится. "Nested Sets", вроде бы, используется в WordPress.